# Jenkins can't find file on the slave/agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have changed our Jenkins setup from everything running on one machine to a master-agent/slave setup. Before that everything worked fine, now I am facing issues that some programs I am calling that access files can't find them.

**Case 1:**
(Pls don't ask why it is so complicated, but the file structure is given and I can't change it)
I am calling a python script, that iself calls a batch file

```
filepath= os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pamFolder, "run.bat"))
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, cwd=pamFolder, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

... and the batch file again a jar file with the actual program

```
java -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -cp "../..;../../libs/*" -jar ..\..\myjarfile.jar
```

Within the jar file there is an access to a file on the disk failing with an error message that the file can't be found:

```
ERR : The file was not found in the specified path 'U:\somefile.txt'. Please check this path for access and your configuration!
```

**Case 2:**
I am calling a batch file from Jenkins that is calling some other exe and in the end trying to open a file in Excel via the COM interface. Here I am getting the following exception (Excel can't access the file):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Excel kann auf die Datei 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\myJob\someDir\someFile.xlsm' nicht zugreifen.
```

**Question**
As previously mentioned, both jobs were working in the previous setup. Both files DO exist.
I suspect that Jenkins / the programs are trying to find the files on the master where they are not available.

Is there any way to tell Jenkins that the called tools are fully executed on the slave node or in some other way tell them where to find these files?

**EDIT**
The job is already running on the slave. The console shows Running on [slave name] in D:/Jenkins/workspace/xxxxx.
The master is configured in a way that only jobs assigned to it run on the master. So pretty much all jobs should run on the slave.

**EDIT2 / SOLUTION**
It turned out that the 2 issues are caused by different things.
Case1: Solved this by using the UNC path
Case2: Solved by a mixture of giving the necessary permissions as described [here](https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/error-office-interop-assemblies/) and starting the slave service with a user with admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with this issue, usually it has to do with your SCM setup.

But as you stated that the files DO exist I think there might be the possibility that U:\ is a network share? Then consider changing your path to use a UNC path.

If that's not the case check if your jenkins slave as sufficient user rights to access said file.

Comment: U is in fact a network share. I can try to use UNC, however, in case 2 the file is on a local drive and it still doesn't work. And also: it did work before changing to master-slave...

Comment: Then it's probably related to the user rights. You can follow these steps [here](https://emilwypych.com/2017/02/07/jenkins-windows-slave-agent-service/?cn-reloaded=1) to setup your slave as a service.

Then open up services, find the service you've setup and modify it's properties. Under the log on tab, choose this account and enter the credentials for an administrative account that you'd like to use.

Comment: It turned out that the 2 issues are caused by different things. Using the UNC path did work, thank you!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad I could be of help. Do consider marking your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Jenkins to run the job on the designated slave as follows:

1. Under **Nodes** > **[SLAVE]** > **Configure**, specify a label for the slave.

[image]

2. Under **[Job]** > **Configure** > **Restrict where this project can be run**, enter the label.

[image]

Now when you build, the console output of the job should read correctly along the lines `Running on [SLAVE] (build_agent_01) in C:/jenkins` and the files must be accessible.

Comment: It is already running on the slave, I will add this information above. The console shows `Running on xxxxx  in D:/Jenkins/workspace/xxxxx`. The master is configured in a way that only jobs assigned to it run on the master. So pretty much all jobs should run on the slave

Comment: In that case, you probably want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760910/8895640